# toggleFold() method doesn't exist

Tags: flutter

I am making a flutter project and I get an error to the code when I use toggleFold(). This method is used even in the example , but I don't know why it doesn't work, the code should be updated? or I should create this method.. and if yes, what this method should contain? I added the package folding cell, main.dart

```
class FoldingCellSimpleDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  final _foldingCellKey = GlobalKey<SimpleFoldingCellState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: SimpleFoldingCell.create(
        key: _foldingCellKey,
        frontWidget: _buildFrontWidget(),
        innerWidget: _buildInnerWidget(),
        cellSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 140),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        borderRadius: 10,
        onOpen: () => print('cell opened'),
        onClose: () => print('cell closed'),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFrontWidget() {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFFffcd3c),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "CARD TITLE",
              style: GoogleFonts.aldrich(
                color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 5,
            bottom: 0,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => _foldingCellKey?.currentState?.toggleFold(),
              child: Text(
                "OPEN",
              ),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.indigoAccent,
              splashColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildInnerWidget() {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFFecf2f9),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Text(
              "CARD TITLE",
              style: GoogleFonts.aldrich(
                color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
                fontSize: 22.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "CARD DETAIL",
              style: GoogleFonts.aldrich(
                color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
                fontSize: 40.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 5,
            bottom: 0,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => _foldingCellKey?.currentState?.toggleFold(),
              child: Text(
                "Close",
              ),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.indigoAccent,
              splashColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `toggleFold` method exists in state? You can try to debug your app and detect type of current state class.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/folding_cell

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Use `Expandable` Here is the Example :
Add package :

> ```
> import 'package:expandable/expandable.dart';
> ```

```
import 'package:expandable/expandable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Expandable Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() {
    return MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Expandable Demo"),
      ),
      body: ExpandableTheme(
        data:
            const ExpandableThemeData(
                iconColor: Colors.blue,
                useInkWell: true,
            ),
        child: ListView(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          children: <Widget>[
            Card1(),
            Card2(),
            Card3(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

const loremIpsum =
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

class Card1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpandableNotifier(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Card(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 150,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ScrollOnExpand(
              scrollOnExpand: true,
              scrollOnCollapse: false,
              child: ExpandablePanel(
                theme: const ExpandableThemeData(
                  headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
                  tapBodyToCollapse: true,
                ),
                header: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Text(
                      "ExpandablePanel",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2,
                    )),
                collapsed: Text(
                  loremIpsum,
                  softWrap: true,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
                expanded: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    for (var _ in Iterable.generate(5))
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                          child: Text(
                            loremIpsum,
                            softWrap: true,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                          )),
                  ],
                ),
                builder: (_, collapsed, expanded) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10),
                    child: Expandable(
                      collapsed: collapsed,
                      expanded: expanded,
                      theme: const ExpandableThemeData(crossFadePoint: 0),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class Card2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    buildImg(Color color, double height) {
      return SizedBox(
          height: height,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: color,
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            ),
          ));
    }

    buildCollapsed1() {
      return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Expandable",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]);
    }

    buildCollapsed2() {
      return buildImg(Colors.lightGreenAccent, 150);
    }

    buildCollapsed3() {
      return Container();
    }

    buildExpanded1() {
      return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Expandable",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "3 Expandable widgets",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]);
    }

    buildExpanded2() {
      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: buildImg(Colors.lightGreenAccent, 100)),
              Expanded(child: buildImg(Colors.orange, 100)),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: buildImg(Colors.lightBlue, 100)),
              Expanded(child: buildImg(Colors.cyan, 100)),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );
    }

    buildExpanded3() {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              loremIpsum,
              softWrap: true,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    return ExpandableNotifier(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10),
      child: ScrollOnExpand(
        child: Card(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expandable(
                collapsed: buildCollapsed1(),
                expanded: buildExpanded1(),
              ),
              Expandable(
                collapsed: buildCollapsed2(),
                expanded: buildExpanded2(),
              ),
              Expandable(
                collapsed: buildCollapsed3(),
                expanded: buildExpanded3(),
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 1,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Builder(
                    builder: (context) {
                      var controller = ExpandableController.of(context);
                      return FlatButton(
                        child: Text(
                          controller.expanded ? "COLLAPSE" : "EXPAND",
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .button
                              .copyWith(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          controller.toggle();
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class Card3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    buildItem(String label) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Text(label),
      );
    }

    buildList() {
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          for (var i in [1, 2, 3, 4]) buildItem("Item ${i}"),
        ],
      );
    }

    return ExpandableNotifier(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: ScrollOnExpand(
        child: Card(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ExpandablePanel(
                theme: const ExpandableThemeData(
                  headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
                  tapBodyToExpand: true,
                  tapBodyToCollapse: true,
                  hasIcon: false,
                ),
                header: Container(
                  color: Colors.indigoAccent,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        ExpandableIcon(
                          theme: const ExpandableThemeData(
                            expandIcon: Icons.arrow_right,
                            collapseIcon: Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                            iconColor: Colors.white,
                            iconSize: 28.0,
                            iconRotationAngle: math.pi / 2,
                            iconPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                            hasIcon: false,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                            "Items",
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .body2
                                .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                expanded: buildList(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: where u r using for loop?